# PostgreSQL 11 - Tuning of the background writer process (maxwritten_clean)

Tags: configuration, postgresql-11

I notice that the metric `maxwritten_clean` in the table `pg_stat_bgwriter` increases (for example going from 0 to 1000 in several seconds). I guess this is understandable as it happens while there are some spikes of writes in the database. According to the documentation, this behavior is driven by the parameter `bgwriter_lru_maxpages` but I can't find any recommendations/best practices on how to set this parameter.

Therefore, I've several questions:

1. Is it bad to see this counter increasing?
2. Do you have any ratio to share to have some kind of alerting on it?
3. Is it a good idea to update the parameter `bgwriter_lru_maxpages` in order to reduce the number of occurrences of `maxwritten_clean`?

Thanks a lot for your help,